# prototype functions in a javascript file loaded by requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

When I put this code in a script.js file and include it runs fine,

but when I implement this code in a javascript file loaded by requirejs the createMapOnOverlay function is not found which is called from outside like this:

```
var overlay = new AlarmOverlay(...);
overlay.createMapOnOverlay(..);
```

**alarmoverlay.js:**

```
AlarmOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

/* constructor */
function AlarmOverlay(bounds, alarmNumber, alarmCssClass) {

    // initialize all properties for an alarm
    this.bounds = bounds;
    this.alarmNumber = alarmNumber;
    this.alarmCssClass = alarmCssClass;
}

AlarmOverlay.prototype.createMapOnOverlay = function(map) {
    // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay
    this.map = map;
    this.setMap(map);
};

AlarmOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function () {


};

AlarmOverlay.prototype.draw = function () {


};
```

I have to put the above code in this below script.js file which is loaded by requirejs:
but the below code does not work

```
define(function() {
    return function AlarmOverlay(bounds, alarmNumber, alarmCssClass) {

        var self = this;

        self.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

        self.bounds = bounds;
        self.alarmNumber = alarmNumber;
        self.alarmCssClass = alarmCssClass;      


        //AlarmOverlay.prototype.createMapOnOverlay = function(map) {      
           self.map = map;
           self.setMap(map);

        //};

        AlarmOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

        };

        AlarmOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

        };
    };
});
```

How do I have to derive from the google OverlayView that I can call the createMapOnOverlay function from outside which should call the setMap from the base class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in AlarmOverlay.js:

```
define(['google'], function(google) {

AlarmOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

/* constructor */
function AlarmOverlay(bounds, alarmNumber, alarmCssClass) {

    // initialize all properties for an alarm
    this.bounds = bounds;
    this.alarmNumber = alarmNumber;
    this.alarmCssClass = alarmCssClass;
}

AlarmOverlay.prototype.createMapOnOverlay = function(map) {
    // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay
    this.map = map;
    this.setMap(map);
};

AlarmOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function () {


};

AlarmOverlay.prototype.draw = function () {


};


return AlarmOverlay;

}
```

and in main js file:

```
require(['AlarmOverlay'], function(AlarmOverlay) {
var overlay = new AlarmOverlay(...);
overlay.createMapOnOverlay(..);
}
```